# Parking a bike in Basel for a week

Tags: bicycles, basel

I am planning a bike tour ending in Basel. From there I would like to take a bus to somewhere else and return to Basel 7-8 days later. I would then like to retrieve my non-motorized bicycle and go for another bike tour in another direction.

Is there something like a bike parking service where I could leave my bike and then pick it up again about a week later in exchange for a daily or weekly fee?

Comment: @JonCuster No, I won't be staying at a hotel. I will leave Basel the same day I will arrive there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there are at least [three bike parking locations](https://www.velostation.ch/velostationen/basel-3/) connected to the railways or stations.
The site is a bit confusing for me, having to translate it from German, but it seems that one (or more) of them are free and at least 2 charge 1 Swiss Frank per day, 12 frank for a monthly pass.
That site has e-mail addresses and telephone numbers as well as website links, so you can contact them or go to their site to find more information.

If the link does not work for whatever reason, `basel bike parking` got me several other links, mostly to the same parking places.
I found that link in [this discussion on parking a bike](https://www.englishforum.ch/housing-general/276817-basel-alstadt-bike-storage.html) on a Switzerland forum.